# Is an Xcode command line tool project allowed CoreLocation permissions?

Tags: xcode, command-line, permissions, core-location

I have a Xcode 'Command Line Tool' project written in C++. I recently added the CoreLocation framework and associated code to find the users location.

Usually, when I implement the CoreLocation framework OS X will ask to me grant permission for the application. This doesn't happen with my Command Line Tool. Is it because there is no associated window / menu?

Also, if I try to manually enable permission in the System Preferences pane under Security > Privacy it automatically gets disabled each time I run the application - even though I've explicitly allowed access.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have an example Xcode project if anyone would like to experience the issue first hand.

Comment: It looks like it should be possible; did you try http://code.google.com/p/corelocationcli/ ?

Comment: Thanks Phil that's exactly what I need. I can't understand why that project asks for location permission but mine doesn't? Is it something to do with NSRunLoop?

Comment: Toby, did you solve your problem? do you have NSRunLoop in your main? if not, that should be the problem.

Comment: Yeah the NSRunLoop allowed the framework to request permission.

Answer (score 2):

Some things under Mac OS need a connection to the window server. An example of that is `NSImage`, and it might be that the location services also requires such a connection.

However, I do not know how to make such connection without calling `NSApplicationMain`.

What you could do is write an auxiliary application that does not show up in the dock (like a status bar application) but calls `NSApplicationMain`. This app would then do all location services and communicate with the calling process (your CLI) through the stdout or sockets or something similar.

Comment: Hi, I imagined it would be something like this - the status bar application is a good idea.

Comment: Remember you don't necessarily need an icon in your status bar. Have a look at LSBackgroundOnly ( http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?LSBackgroundOnly )

Answer (score 1):

Are you also importing Foundation.h into your project?  You should check to see all the dependencies that CoreLocation has and make sure they are making it into your project.  CoreLocation is also written in Objective-C so some of the calls may not be caught by c++ your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

when CoreLocation ask for location data, the Mac will prompt a message box ask user to give the permission, if you check the Don't ask me again and click the OK, then it will never prompt the message again unless you "Reset Warnings" under Security preference pane, but if you move the command line app to another directory, the Mac will ask for permission again. I believe this permission is stored with full path of the application.